# Unable to change virtual terminal

Tags: virtual-console

I am currently running on a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, and I am unable to change virtual terminal. I tried using the keyboard shortcut CTRL+ALT+F[1-6] which doesn't do anything and the command `sudo chvt N` (with N = [2-6]) stays running in my console but doesn't do anything either.

Is there anything I could to to be able to switch virtual terminal ?

Thanks in advance!